# ShardCollection fails with error "couldn't find valid index for shard key" & code: "96" &

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

**Consider**:
I have a collection called "Feeds", "Groups" and "Users" and there are millions of document in them.
Say "Feeds" schema is as follows:

```
{
    fromUserRef: <Reference Id from Users collection>,
    toUsersRef: [<Array of Reference Id(s) from Users collection>],
    toGroupsRef: [<Array of Reference Id(s) from Groups collection>],
    text: <String>,
    image: <String>,
    ...
}
```

**Sample Documents:**

```
{
    fromUserRef: ObjectId("5dd4e8b52355555592249596"),
    toUsersRef: [],
    toGroupsRef: [ObjectId("5dd4e8b523594c5592249392")],
    ...
},
{
    fromUserRef: ObjectId("5dd4e8b52355555592249583"),
    toUsersRef: [ObjectId("5dd4e8b52355555592249596"), ObjectId("5dd4e8b52355555592249291")],
    toGroupsRef: [],
    ...
},
{
    fromUserRef: ObjectId("5dd4e8b52355555592249583"),
    toUsersRef: [],
    toGroupsRef: [],
    ...
}
```

Now say I chose the shard key with "toUsersRef" & "toGroupsRef". According to the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key-indexes) there must be an index that supports the shard key.

In my case, I have created an **index** as follows:

```
db.feeds.createIndex({ 
    "toUserRef" : 1,
    "toGroupsRef" : 1
},
{"name":"toUsersRef_1_toGroupsRef_1"})
```

**Shard Collection:**

```
sh.shardCollection("my_db.feeds", {
    "toUsersRef" : 1,   "toGroupsRef" : 1
 });
```

**Error Output:**

```
{
   "message" : "couldn't find valid index for shard key",
   "ok" : 0,
   "code" : 96,
   "codeName" : "OperationFailed",
   "operationTime" : "Timestamp(1578373028, 5)",
   "$clusterTime" : {
       "clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1578373028, 5)",
       "signature" : {
           "hash" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
           "keyId" : 0
       }
   },
   "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Not sure what's wrong here. Could anyone put some light on this?

**P.S**: To make index strategy must be the same as shard strategy, tried the same shard key on an empty collection & copied the index which is created to support the shard key and re-attempted to shard collection where data exists, but no luck it throws the same error.

**More info**:
Using MongoDB versions: 4.2.2
config server cluster/replica set, 2 shard cluster/replica servers
while creating index/shard collection was connected to mongos

---

> **Finally found the root cause**

It was working on new collection but not on existing because the create index had a typo in it [ **s** was missing :| ]. & once corrected the typo getting error as `cannot index parallel arrays [toUsersRef] [toGroupsRef]`

Comment: Did you enable sharding on the database using `sh.enableSharding()`? Also, see this if you have missed anything: [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html#enable-sharding-for-a-database).

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, sharding is enabled, As I mentioned I create a new collection with the same shard key which is in the same DB.

Comment: What do you mean by _new collection with the same shard key..._?

Comment: You have to follow these steps in the following order: (1) sh.enableSharding, (2) create index on the collection to be sharded. and (3) shard the collection (sh.shardCollection).

Comment: By new collection I meant I create empty collection with name feedss (notice extra 's') and then shard collection with same key i.e ` "toUsersRef" : 1,   "toGroupsRef" : 1` and this will create an index right? I copied that index to old collection where data exists and then tried to shard collection, that too fails..

Comment: Yes, followed. (1) sh.enableSharding, (2) create an index on the collection to be shared and (3) shard the collection (sh.shardCollection). At step 3 it fails only for the collection where data exists (new empty collection which is in same db it works)

Comment: What does the `sh.status()` show?

Comment: Its print the expected shard metadata, database name `my_db` is present in the output's databases

Comment: Please add the sh.status results in the question post.

Comment: Finally found the issue, it was working on new collection but not on existing because the create index had a typo in it [ **s** was missing :| ]. & once corrected the typo getting error as `cannot index parallel arrays [toUsersRef] [toGroupsRef]`
Thanks for your time @prasad_

Answer (score 0):

Shard key index cannot be multi-key (i.e. fields indexed cannot be arrays).